# Open repository of political logos/images

Tags: data-request, images, politics

I'm looking for political logos (images). Images should be able to be bulk downloaded, if possible. I've found a source from the US, but I'd like to collect from other countries/regions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One source for the US (2018 election) is

https://www.politicsanddesign.com/

> The first of its kind, this collection consists of every campaign logo from the 2018 election for United States Congress. The archive is a tool to explore trends and typologies that reveal themselves only when viewed in aggregate.

(they offer a bulk download on demand, and I'll post a link to the export here, if its license permits.)

---

Example screenshot:

[image]